# How to set initial height for CKEditor + div editing area

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 4 with div editing area plugin. by default when using **iframe mode**, height is set to number of rows set in  and it will re size as text grows. Now because I'm using div area plugin, the default height is not affected by the value set in  but depends on the text that is inside . how to fix this??

if i manually change the height here then textarea will not expand.

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="cke_wysiwyg_div cke_reset cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" hidefocus="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_128">
    <p>This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.</p>
    </div>

    <span id="cke_128" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.height = '800px';
};
```

if this dont work, you could try this : 
http://www.stepcoder.com/Articles/10003/how-to-set-or-change-height-of-ckediotr-textbox-area-using-asp-net

Comment: Doesn't work. the link you provided the same thing you just said.